# How to remove "Edit" button in "More" view in a tab based iphone application

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I am facing a small problem. As we all know, if you have more than 5 tabs, iOS will add a "More" button and display the other bar items in the "More" view with a "Edit" button. Due to some reasons, I'd like to remove this button. I tried the below method, somehow, it doesn't work.

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: Have you got any error then let us know. It helps to customize the first 4 tabs, so if 'edit' button is removed then user wont customize it. So think b4 doing so.

Comment: No error, but no effect as well.

Comment: Then, I am not sure, but thinks apple dont allows developer to do this. Apple rejects apps that tampers with frameworks policies, I mean you can customize your own tab bar but cant play with apple provided  UITabBar

Comment: Then, I need find some ways to avoid it. Do you know how I can change "Edit" to some other words? I don't know how to localize the text for the default bar buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tabBarController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Please add delegate for Navigation in your `viewDidLoad`.

```
self.navigationController.delegate = self;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, set the delegate of the moreNavigationController.

```
moreNavigationController.delegate = self
```

Then you can change the navigation items in this delegate method:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    // remove edit button in 'more' table view
    navigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always hide it and then disable it like so:

```
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.clear 
self.tabBarController?.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
```

Changing the UIColor to clear makes it invisible and then by disabling its functionality, it renders it completely impossible to use while simultaneously making it invisible.